# What happens if I run WAITFOR from C# and the .NET app crashes?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# app that executes SQL Server commands sequentially, in a single batch, using Entity Framework. Something like this:

```
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Insert into tbl1...;
WAITFOR delay '00:00:02.000';
Delete from tbl1 where...");
```

One of the commands is WAITFOR, which requires the DB to wait for about 2 secs before continuing to the next statement.

What will happen if the app will crash while the WAITFOR is running? Will SQL Server still wait for the defined time and then execute the commands, or will it stop in the middle?

Thanks!

Comment: @Fabio - not so clear. Read [related question on dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/47404/6381)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - The related question deals with a transaction, and with a situation when the client does not want the update to continue. My purpose is the opposite - I want the DB to keep waiting in WAITFOR and then execute the command right after that. What is the best practice for that?

Comment: If you want to "guarantee" that work will continue at some time in the future, you need to get it independently scheduled and not on your connection. An SQL Agent job is the obvious manner to do this, but it's fitting for *regular work* rather than *ad hoc queries*. What's the nature of your task?

Comment: Are you using ExecuteCommand or BeginExecuteCommand?  First is blocking and second is non blocking.  You doun't need a WAITFOR if the method is blocking.

Comment: I want to make sure a record I add to a table will be deleted after two seconds, and I want it to happen even if the C# client has crashed. What would be the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Most reliable is to try and change the contract - why do you need to create and then remove a row with a 2 second window?

Comment: I need that in order to implement a DB-based cross-server timeout mechanism. I need that all the servers in the farm will know when a specific timeout has passed, and they'll know that by making sure a specific row in not in the table. Please note this is a fallback mechanism and we have other timeout alternatives in the works, but we want to explore this option too.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I believe the client would have sent the entire batch to server and if client crashes the server will still execute the commands until a specific kill command is issued.

One approach is throw the code into a stored procedure and simply call the procedure. This way all the code will execute as long as it was called.

If your purpose is to delete the record even if the client crashes then you could try a SQL agent job approach as suggested. This way your client is not waiting till deletion is done (unless this is what you want) For this to work you would have to have a record inserted date time in the table so that you can scan the table every two minutes and delete rows based on record insert date time.

If you want more complex but reliable solution you could use Service broker where you could queue the record to be deleted and a separate process can delete it. Service broker might be too much for this simple task. But it depends on how stable you want the deletion to be.

Nachi

Comment: So just to make sure I've got it - If the code is within a stored procedure, then even if the client crashed - the procedure will complete its execution. Is that correct?

Comment: @ml123 - no, there's no guarantee of that. If SQL Server detects a broken connection, it will rollback any open transactions and terminate the batch.

Comment: But isn't rollback sufficient? So if the batch is being executed within the context of a transaction, either the row will be deleted - or - the insert will be rolled back, which is equivalent?

Comment: Actually, I need that the insertion of the row will be commited (so other queries be able to see it), and then wait for 2 secs and delete it, so it won't be all in the same transaction.

Comment: Another options would be is call a stored procedure and let that procedure call a SQL Agent job (asynchronously) , inside the SQL job do the insertion, wait, and delete. Since the job is called asynchronously it will return to main proc right after the call and the job will complete. This may not work if you want to insert into a table with custom values.